# How do I retrieve the number of columns in a Pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do you programmatically retrieve the number of columns in a pandas dataframe? I was hoping for something like:

```
df.num_columns
```

Comment: I am looking for a solution that takes into account also columns that are turned into (multi)index after groupby operation. I figured out `len(df.axes[0].names)+df.shape[1]` but it looks far from optimal. Any ideas? None of the existing answers address that now.

Comment: @jangorecki That's not at all related to this question though. If things are in the Index of a DataFrame, they are **not** considered a column. While this might seem like a somewhat arbitrary distinction, pandas treats the Index values and column Series _very_ differently for certain manipulations. Anyway, you can prevent the creation of a `MultiIndex` with `as_index=False` when you groupby.

Comment: @ALollz the fact they are not considered a column is just pandas specifics, engineers coming from SQL, R and other techs will expect grouping columns to be columns, not an attribute.

Comment: @jangorecki  One easy way would be `len(df.reset_index().columns)` as reset_index will convert all indexes to columns.  But this is really a distinct question as @Aloltz notes.  I'd recommend just asking a new question with  a proper sample data set and give the bounty here to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 409, accepted):

Like so:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"pear": [1,2,3], "apple": [2,3,4], "orange": [3,4,5]})

len(df.columns)
3
```

Comment: plus `df.shape` gives a tuple with (n_rows, n_columns)

Comment: @mkln  if you post df.shape[1] as an answer, I'd +1.  This is the better way to work with numpy and deserves to be a separate answer.

Comment: done. @PhilCooper perhaps you could explain why `df.shape` is better? my guess is that it does not call a function but just reads the attribute from memory?

Answer (score 136):

Alternative:

```
df.shape[1]
```

(`df.shape[0]` is the number of rows)

Comment: +1 because I like to encourage addressing of numpy and pandas objects with martix type syntax. (df.shape vs len(df.columns)).  Truth be told, if you look at the pandas descriptor for shape, it calls len(df.columns) but numpy arrays and matricies have them as an attribute.  most efficient vectorized operations can be done with regular python syntas as opposed to vectorized operations and is almost always wrong (numba/jit operations excepted from that criticizm)

Answer (score 37):

If the variable holding the dataframe is called df, then:

```
len(df.columns)
```

gives the number of columns.

And for those who want the number of rows:

```
len(df.index)
```

For a tuple containing the number of both rows and columns:

```
df.shape
```

Comment: Wouldn't `len(df)` give you the rows?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham pandas has so many shortcuts that are easy to forget so I prefer to ignore them and and use the main logic instead to solve things. You may sacrifice processing speed sometimes, but I value my coding time and code readability more than a few seconds of processing time.
In this particular case: if you learn that the number of rows can be calculated with len(df.index), next time you need the number of columns it comes natural to do len(df.columns).

Answer (score 6):

Surprised I haven't seen this yet, so without further ado, here is:

[df.columns.size](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.size.html?highlight=size#pandas.Index.size)

Answer (score 1):

df.info() function will give you result something like as below. 
If you are using read_csv method of Pandas without sep parameter or sep with ",".

```
raw_data = pd.read_csv("a1:\aa2/aaa3/data.csv")
raw_data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5144 entries, 0 to 5143
Columns: 145 entries, R_fighter to R_age
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple option to get column number and column information such as:
let's check them.

local_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,12,size=(2,6)),columns =['a','b','c','d','e','f']) 
1. local_df.shape[1]   --> Shape attribute return tuple as (row & columns) (0,1).

2. local_df.info()     --> info Method will return detailed information about data frame and it's columns such column count, data type of columns, 
                           Not null value count, memory usage by Data Frame
3. len(local_df.columns) --> columns attribute will return index object of data frame columns & len function will return total available columns.
4. local_df.head(0)    --> head method with parameter 0 will return 1st row of df which actually nothing but header.

Assuming number of columns are not more than 10. For loop fun:
li_count =0
for x in local_df:
    li_count =li_count + 1
print(li_count)

Answer (score 0):

In order to include the number of row index "columns" in your total shape I would personally add together the number of columns `df.columns.size` with the attribute `pd.Index.nlevels`/`pd.MultiIndex.nlevels`:

Set up dummy data

```
import pandas as pd

flat_index = pd.Index([0, 1, 2])
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 1), names=["letter", "id"])

columns = ["cat", "dog", "fish"]

data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
flat_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=flat_index, columns=columns)
multi_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=multi_index, columns=columns)

# Show data
# -----------------
# 3 columns, 4 including the index
print(flat_df)
    cat  dog  fish
id                
0     1    2     3
1     4    5     6
2     7    8     9

# -----------------
# 3 columns, 5 including the index
print(multi_df)
           cat  dog  fish
letter id                
a      1     1    2     3
       2     4    5     6
b      1     7    8     9
```

Writing our process as a function:

```
def total_ncols(df, include_index=False):
    ncols = df.columns.size
    if include_index is True:
        ncols += df.index.nlevels
    return ncols

print("Ignore the index:")
print(total_ncols(flat_df), total_ncols(multi_df))

print("Include the index:")
print(total_ncols(flat_df, include_index=True), total_ncols(multi_df, include_index=True))
```

This prints:

```
Ignore the index:
3 3

Include the index:
4 5
```

If you want to only include the number of indices if the index is a `pd.MultiIndex`, then you can throw in an `isinstance` check in the defined function.

As an alternative, you could use `df.reset_index().columns.size` to achieve the same result, but this won't be as performant since we're temporarily inserting new columns into the index and making a new index before getting the number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
#use a regular expression to parse the column count
#https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

buffer = io.StringIO()
df.info(buf=buffer)
s = buffer.getvalue()
pat=re.search(r"total\s{1}[0-9]\s{1}column",s)
print(s)
phrase=pat.group(0)
value=re.findall(r'[0-9]+',phrase)[0]
print(int(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"pear": [1,2,3], "apple": [2,3,4], "orange": [3,4,5]})


print(len(list(df.iterrows())))
```

gives length of rows

```
3

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score 0):

here is:

- `pandas`

  - excel engine: `xlsxwriter`

several method to get **column count**:

- `len(df.columns)` -> `28`

  - [image]
- `df.shape[1]` -> `28`

  - here: `df.shape = (592, 28)`
  - related

    - rows count: `df.shape[0]` -> `592`
- `df.columns.shape[0]` -> `28`

  - here: `df.columns.shape = (28,)`

    - [image]
- `df.columns.size` -> `28`

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me len(list(df)).

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.

Comment: Don't do that. It creates a new list, wasting memory and speed.